# C# Razor, repeated Partial pages in a web page use the same data instead of haveing their own data

Tags: c#, razor, partial

I have a web page in which I want to display the same partial windrose chart 2 times with 2 different sets of data.  However whatever data is returned for the 1st partial page is incorrectly used for the second partial page.

```
            <div class="A">
            @{
                var YAxis = Model.GetWindroseReadings(0);
                var ChartName = "Chart1Hour";
                await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { YAxis, ChartName });
            }
        </div>
        <div class="B">
            @{
                YAxis = Model.GetWindroseReadings(1);
                ChartName = "Chart24Hour";
                await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { YAxis, ChartName });
            }
        </div>
```

YAxis is an html string.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're rendering async but passing object that is the same object and changing its data. Don't re-use the object like that.

```
<div class="A">
            @{
                var YAxis1 = Model.GetWindroseReadings(0);
                var ChartName1 = "Chart1Hour";
                await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { YAxis1, ChartName1 });
            }
        </div>
        <div class="B">
            @{
                var YAxis2 = Model.GetWindroseReadings(1);
                var ChartName2 = "Chart24Hour";
                await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { YAxis2, ChartName2 });
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: I hope this is the answer, thankyou. However I get an error: Invalid anonymous type declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment.

Comment: Updated code.:             <div class="A">
                @{
                    var ChartName = "Chart1Hour";
                    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { Model.GetWindroseReadings(0), ChartName });
                }
            </div>
            <div class="B">
                @{
                    ChartName = "Chart24Hour";
                    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { Model.GetWindroseReadings(1), ChartName });
                }
            </div>

Comment: Don't I have to use a Name so that the partial page picks up on it?

Comment: Perhaps, try that first variation first, it's basically what you did that works just doesn't re-use the variable. If the first one fixes your trouble, try the second but don't use an anonymous object, should you wish to make the code more concise: send a typed model in as the object. (you didn't post your model so I don't know the property names)

Comment: I seem to have lost my last comment.  How do I use a partial page with different incoming variable names?  In the partial page I have: Model.YAxis and Model.ChartName, don't these have to match up with the incoming variable names?

Comment: I edited the answer to only use the first variation. Let me know if that works.

Comment: In the model I just have a function that returns an html string.

Comment: Your view ChartWindroseVariable takes a model, right? What's the shape of that model? See also this answer about how partials share models if you aren't explicitly separating them out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673172/error-creating-renderpartialasync-problem-in-controller

Comment: Mmmm, now you might be finding the limits of my understanding.  I had understood that a partial view picks up the model from the web page view so all I do in the partial view is use Model.YAxis and Model.ChartName. In the model I have a function that returns an html string.  All this works except for the reuse of the 1st data. If I use different variable names calling the same partial view I get an error that prevents the partial view from loading.

Comment: Ah HA  =)  No, that's perfect, I assumed you were passing an actual model because I saw the overload passing an object. So really what's going on is still async shenanigans because these things don't render linearly and the value of the underlying objects in the model is changing. At least I assume that's what up, without a debugger to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I am using:

```
            <div class="A">
            @{
                var yAxis0 = Model.GetWindroseReadings(0);
                var ChartName = "Chart1Hour";
                await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { YAxis = yAxis0, ChartName });
            }
        </div>
        <div class="B">
            @{
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                var yAxis1 = Model.GetWindroseReadings(1);
                ChartName = "Chart24Hour";
                await Html.RenderPartialAsync("Charts/Partial/ChartWindroseVariable", new { YAxis = yAxis1, ChartName });
            }
        </div>
```

Looking at the web page source I am correctly getting different strings of data for each of the partial views, so now my problem seems to be with HighCharts rendering.

Thank you for your help, I'll now go and look at the web page rendering.